# Why is $\forall xO(x,c), \forall xO(c,x) \therefore \forall xO(x,x)$ an invalid reasoning?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

> Why is $\forall xO(x,c), \forall xO(c,x) \therefore \forall xO(x,x)$ an invalid reasoning?

This exercise appears in P.D. Magnus. *"forallX: an Introduction to Formal Logic"* (p. 268, exercise D. 7).

I think to satisfy both universal quantifiers, predicate $O$ must be symmetric, so I cannot find an interpretation that makes $\forall xO(x,x)$ false. On the surface, it seems a valid reasoning (considering a non-empty universe).

What's happening here?

Comment: How about $2^x$ vs $x^2$ vs $x^x$? Just a thought.

Comment: What if $O(x,y)$ means $xy=0$ and $c=0$?

Comment: [This proof tree generator](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#(%E2%88%80x(O(x,c))%E2%88%A7%E2%88%80x(O(c,x)))%E2%86%92(%E2%88%80x(O(x,x)))) gives a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. @JPMcCarthy, that's an interesting example. What is $O$ defined in your case and what is its domain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As computed [here](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#(%E2%88%80x(O(x,c))%E2%88%A7%E2%88%80x(O(c,x)))%E2%86%92(%E2%88%80x(O(x,x)))), let the domain be $\{0,1\}$, let $c=0$, and let $O$ be given by $\{(0,0), (0,1), (1,0)\}$, so that $\exists z\lnot O(z,z)$, namely, $z=1$.

Answer (score 3):

> On the surface, it seems a valid reasoning (considering a non-empty universe). What's happening, here ?

Since there are already some answers that give neat concrete counterexamples to the claim, I will try to give you an intuitive picture of why it is not a valid inference.

The statement $\forall x O(x,c)$ says that $O$ is true for all $x$ when $x$ is on the left, and the statement $\forall x O(c,x)$ says that $O$ is true for all $x$ when $x$ is on the right. Although it appears to be all about $x$, this is really more of a statement about $c$. It simply says that $c$ makes $O$ true whenever it appears on the left or the right. $x$ is just a dummy variable we use to write this statement formally—it is standing in for *anything* in the domain.

Once you realise this, it should be fairly obvious that $O(x,x)$ is not necessarily true for all $x$. If $x \neq c$ then we have no guarantee that $O$ is true in this case, as our original statement only refers to situations involving $c$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your excellent and detailed answer !

Answer (score 2):

Remember that validity means the argument is valid under *all* interpretations, so to refute it, it suffices to come up with one counter example.

To go at your intuition, it often helps to think of a more informal interpretation. Think of a classroom setting, where $O$ stands for "sees" and $c$ refers to the teacher. Everyone can see the teacher, and the teacher sees everyone, including the himself in a reflection in the window, so $\forall x O(c,x)$ and $\forall x O(x,c)$ are true. But the students sitting in the front row can't see themselves or the students behind them, so $\forall x O(x,x)$ is false.

If you want to write it down in formal notation, to simplify let's say there is just one student in the classroom, then we have
$D = \{Alice, Mrs. Smith\},\\  
F(c) = Mrs. Smith, F(O) = \{\langle Mrs. Smith, Alice \rangle, \langle Mrs. Smith, Mrs. Smith \rangle\}$
as a counter model.

Since there is at least one interpretation of the non-logical symbols where the premises are true but the conclusion is false, the argument can't be valid.

Comment: Thank you very much for your always outstanding help and wonderful explanations, @lemontree !

Comment: What’s the meaning of $F(c)$ and $F(O)$ in your notation ?

Comment: The interpretation of the name $c$ and the prediate $O$, respectively. $F$ is the interpretation function, whose domain are the non-logical symbols and whose range is individuals/sets of tuples from the domain. Possibly the book you're using wirtes it down a bit differently, but the concept is the same across all textbooks.

Comment: Do you remember a particular book where those concepts are mentioned ?

Comment: Just about any not-too-informal logic textbook... IIRC Peter Smith gave you a a recommendation the other day.

Comment: Thank you. I will search in that direction. You're right. Peter Smith said that whenever I feel puzzled by some concept, I should read first chapters of another books. He didn't mention a specific one, though.